# Routing error, uninitialized constant MotorsportsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create an app with motorSports controller but I have an issue with routing. It looks like the name controller is not initialized. In my routes.rb I have the following:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   get "/motorsports", to: 'motorsports#index'
   get "/motorsports/new", to: 'motorsports#new'
   get "/motorsports/:id", to: 'motorsports#show'
   post "/motorsports", to: 'motorsports#create'
   get "/motorsports/:id/edit", to: 'motorsports#edit'
   patch "/motorsports/:id", to: 'motorsports#update'
   delete "/motorsports/:id", to: 'motorsports#destroy'
 end
```

and in my controller I have:

```
class MotorSportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @motorsports = MotorSport.all 
    render "index.html.erb"
  end

  def show
    @motorsport = MotorSport.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    motorsport = MotorSport.new({
      model: params[:model],
      make: params[:make],
      image: params[:image],
      description: params[:description],
      cost: params[:cost],
      speed: params[:speed],
      driver_name: params[:driver_name]
    })
    motorsport.save
    flash[:success] = "Motorsport Created"
    redirect_to "/motorsports/#{motorsport.id}"
  end

  def edit
    @motorsport = MotorSport.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    motorsport = MotorSport.find_by(id: params[:id])
    motorsport.assign_attributes({
      model: params[:model],
      image: params[:image],
      make: params[:make],
      description: params[:description],
      cost: params[:cost],
      speed: params[:speed],
      driver_name: params[:driver_name]
    })
    motorsport.save
    flash[:success] = "Item Updated"
    redirect_to "/motorsports"
  end

  def destroy
    @motorsport = MotorSport.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @motorsport.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Motorsport Deleted!"
    redirect_to "/motorsports"
  end 
end
```

What wrong with my app?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `MotorSportsController` the routes must be like this, notice the underscore in the controller.

```
get "/motorsports", to: 'motor_sports#index'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all routes of MotorSports and add this line.

```
resources motorsports
```